# Multiple errors ocurred while copying files - but, can I see what they are?

Tags: xcode

There were around 200 files I had to delete in my Xcode project (and yeah, they were deleted properly), and now I have to copy 200+ files are supposedly replace the ones I just deleted.

I keep getting "Multiple errors occurred while copying files". The Xcode window doesn't show the newly-added files, but if I explore the project folder using the Finder, I can see that the files were indeed added - well, there most likely was a certain file that could not be copied and thus caused the error. Problem is, I have no idea which one nor why.

Now then, is it possible to get Xcode to tell me what the problem is rather than telling me there is one?

**Edit**: Okay, I did discover that some of the new files shared the same name as some files that were not listed in Xcode, which explains the error. However, I am still interested in knowing whether there is a way to know that the "Multiple errors" actually are whenever Xcode says t his.

Comment: This issue occurs to me because I accidently copy files double.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When Xcode finds a duplicate file, it generates this error, and then it fails to add references for the files that it *did* manage to copy.

Rather than deleting files from the finder and starting over, you can do this:

1. Open the Finder for your project, where your source files are located
2. Command-click the ones for which your references are missing (and if you click others, it won't really matter)
3. Drag them into Xcode. When the confirmation dialog comes up, unset the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" checkbox. This will tell Xcode to make references only.

Comment: Good Answer For me3 line Works.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the files from finder and then added again the files via Xcode, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes occurs when the code is not merged properly. The missing files will not be available in Xcode but once you open the finder containing this project, you will be able to spot the missing file.

The simplest way to add these missing files back to the project is:

1) In your Xcode, navigate to Build Phases Tab.

2) Under Compile Sources, tap on '+' to add back the missing file.

Sometimes the missing files will be greyed out in the build phases, just tap on '-' and add them back.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked. I tried to add files which are already in my bundle. So make sure you are not adding files which are already added. I hope it helps someone.